# Differentiation in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

let $h$ be a map from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. $h(x,y) = xy$. Differentiate $h$ at $(a,b)$.

Comment: Have you done anything before posting this question? What have you tried, how far did you get and how did it fail?

Comment: I tried using directional derivative approach. That total derivation equals directional derivative for any $u$. I got $au_2 + bu_1$ where $u = (u_1, u_2)$

Comment: I think that kind of questions are **very,very** important for everyone. I said this because some of us are using this concepts without understanding deeply this notion. Yes I know how to differentiate this function, but if you ask me to plot this function, to see the geometric meaning I won't be able to understand. In some universities these notions are deeply explained, but not in all. In my university the teacher tell me some definition and "that's all folks". Send us some interesting material for a deeply understanding of these very important notions! Best wishes! For this question $(+1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, the differential of $h$ at $(a,b)$ is (represented by) the vector
$$
\nabla h(a,b)=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\partial h / \partial x \\
\partial h / \partial y
\end{matrix}
\right),
$$
where the partial derivatives are evaluated at $x=a$, $y=b$. In your case,
$$
\nabla h(a,b)=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
b \\
a
\end{matrix}
\right).
$$